# compare a varchar column with a varchar variable does not work

Tags: string, variables, sql-server-2005

I have two block of SQL statements (I am using sql server 2005):

-- 1

```
SELECT *
FROM Invoice
WHERE CustomerId = 'ITTEST01' AND StoreId = '01'

-- CustomerId and StoreId have VARCHAR(16) data type.
```

--2

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @pCustomerId AS VARCHAR(16)

DECLARE @pStoreId AS VARCHAR(16)

SET @pCustomerId = 'ITTEST01'
SET @pStoreId = '01'

SELECT *
FROM Invoice
WHERE CustomerId = @pCustomerId AND StoreId = @pStoreId
END
```

The 1st statement returns what I expect, but the 2nd block returns nothing. I am not sure why this happens as the two SQL blocks should return the same result to me? Could someone give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce this. Is the second sample your actual code, or are you passing in the variables as parameters from somewhere else?

Comment: It is the actual code. If I create a user-defined function to pass 2 varchar(16) parameters to use, the result is the same, just nothing returns. My SQL server version is 9.0.1399.

Comment: I have found the cause of the issue. There is special character in the text literal text of the @pCustomerId in my SQL server management Studio, remove that character fix the issue. Thank Shree for the hint.